# CSS trick for float left without new line but show some and hide remaining

Tags: html, css, css-float

I tried css code in google and find none for a long time. **I can do this by javascript**,

Get the body/parent div's width and height, then place div and hide remaining

or

**By div * nos and add this value to parent div's width and stop overflow.**

I think this trick can be done using css3. If you achieved this by css3, pls post your code.

**My Question demo will be something like this.**

```
<div id="parent">
<div class="small s1">some thing</div>
<div class="small s2">some thing</div>
<div class="small s3">some thing</div>
<div class="small s4">some thing</div>
</div>
```

In this parent will have 500px width and height 500px;
class small will have 300px width and 100px height;

If i apply float for class small i can see this in next line.

I need to show only 2 small div, and the second div must show only 200px and 100px hidden. also s3 and s4 must be hidden.

**IMPORTANT** parent div will be a dynamic value.

Comment: Why down vote? I tried google and later i posted here. Also i cant find any duplicate for this qtn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you try playing around with `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap` which I believe would achieve what you are looking for.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/py3C2/)

For maximum compatibility with IE7 and below, you should however replace the .small divs with spans.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Pervan, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/py3C2/) is what i need. Also thanks for IE7 compatibility.